# Wicket 1.5 - How to configure link generated url?

Tags: security, url, hyperlink, wicket, wicket-1.5

I'm coding a wicket 1.5 application and I need to control the way url are rendered for security reason.

```
mountPage("xxx/yyy", Zzzz.class)
```

is excellent for that but I have a problem with url generated for link listener. For exemple, if I add the following link to my page:

```
add(new Link<Void>("link-login") {
  @Override
  public void onClick() {
    setResponsePage(LoginPage.class);
  }
});
```

I obtain the following generated markup:

```
<a wicket:id="link-login" href="./home?0-1.ILinkListener-accessMenu-link~login">Login</a>
```

Is there a way to configure the generated url (`./home?0-1.ILinkListener-accessMenu-link~login`)? At least, I would like to remove the ~ character.

**EDIT:**
Solved... According to wicket staff, generated href encode the wicket path using '-' as separator. If the wicket id contains a '-', it will be transform in '~' to avoid conflict. So in order to avoid it, just remove '-' from your wicket id.

Comment: Have you checked out org.apache.wicket.core.request.mapper.CryptoMapper?. It gives you the ultimate URL security.

Comment: Please, consider to vote up my last comment below :). Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default character - is reserved as separator for components id. You can have a look here https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/Request+mapping and try to use CryptoMapper if you are concerned about security.

Comment: Tx but my concern is about ~ (tilde), is it possible to change it?

Comment: Moreover, I'm not sure a RequestMapper allow to modify generated href.

Comment: No, I don't think it's possible to modify the generated href, unless you build a custom IRequestMapper implementation. Maybe you could change your component id substituting the - with the _